# Dropdown select in Capybara with no id?

Tags: capybara

So I have a few dropdowns im making some automated test cases for (just checking to make sure links work and go to the right location. Easy test cases to toss in there)

But I don't really have any id's or anything to work with:

Here is the outer HTML of the Dropdown text to click (which reveals more dropdowns).

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Main Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

The rest of the items are listed like this:

```
<li><a href="/quotes"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Option 1</a></li>
```

Would it make more sense to just try to use the clickable text to click on the "Main Dropdown" text and then the clickable text to click on "Option 1" (names were changed but the concept is still the same).

Since that's really all the HTML is in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybaras link finder finds link elements by id, text, title or contained images alt attribute.  With the html provided your best best for those is the text - so

```
click_link('Main Dropdown') # open the dropdown
click_link('Option 1') # wait for the link to become visible and then click it
```

Comment: This seems fragile with the wait though doesn't it?

Comment: @msmith1114  It's no more fragile than waiting for an element by id to appear,  you can adjust the amount of time it will wait for the link to appear by passing wait: <number of seconds> as an option to click_link if desired, or increase Capybara.default_max_wait_time.  Although unless the dropdown is being loaded dynamically you really shouldn't need to, and even if it is being loaded dynamically it really shouldn't take more than 2 (the default value for Capybara.default_max_wait_time) seconds to appear - or your user experience is going to be terrible

Comment: Yeah thats true, plus im running it headless so it should be even faster. Im really not sure why it was coded the way it was. I guess i don't understand why it doesn't have an ID or anything

Comment: It would probably have been coded like that to keep the page small -- if there's no need for an id on the element why add one - all it would do is increase page size.

Comment: sadly it didn't work, i got complaints about: Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body div.navmenu.navmenu-default.navmenu-fixed-left.offcanvas-sm ul.nav.navmenu-nav li.open div.dropdown-backdrop' at this position, which I have no idea what that means

Comment: Have you reset the default of Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements ?  What versions of phantomjs/poltergeist are you using?  That error generally means you have overlapping elements, or potentially animating elements (so the element is moving while trying to be clicked) -- if you're using some kind of animating menu widget try disabling animations when running in test mode.

Comment: This actually ended up working: find("a", :text => /\AOption 1\z/).trigger('click')

Comment: Ok - as long as you understand that triggering the click event via JS is potentially different than a user clicking on the element so you're test is drifting away from simulating what a user could do